# Select products that have stock and products where showWhenNoStock is true

Tags: plugin-craftcommerce

We've been working on a sneaker shop and the product overview page is only showing the products that are in stock. Now the client also wants to show some selected products on the overview even if there is no stock.

To show only the products with stock we've added:

```
hasVariant: {
    hasStock: true
}
```

Is there a way to select products that have stock and products that don't have stock but where `showWhenNoStock` is true?

May be good to know `showWhenNoStock` is a field on the main product not the variant.